# jplayer play button issue when I click on first time that song is not playing.on second click that song is playing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

When I click on first time that song is not playing.on second click that song is playing. here is my code..

```
$(".jp-stop").trigger('click');
var some_data = ([ ]);

var myPlaylist = new jPlayerPlaylist({
    jPlayer: "#jquery_jplayer_2",
    cssSelectorAncestor: "#jp_container_2"
},some_data, {
    swfPath: "<?php echo webroot_url();?>dist/jplayer",
    supplied: "oga, mp3 wmv",
    solution:"flash,html",
    wmode: "window",
    useStateClassSkin: true,
    autoBlur: false,
    smoothPlayBar: true,
    keyEnabled: true
});

myPlaylist.setPlaylist([ ]);
myPlaylist.add({
    title:sname,
    mp3:sname,
    oga:sname
});
$(".jp-play").trigger('click');
```

Comment: did you have any jsfiddle demo?

Comment: no.. actually i call this function playsong(sname) using onclick from that i get the sname.can u help me.first time that is not playing second time that is playing.

Comment: Running into the same problem: My player needs to be clicked twice to play, and I need it to play on one. Is there a solution?